# Delete row ASP.NET MVC ADO.NET entity Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm kinda newbie with asp.net MVC environment

i'm trying to delete ROW from 3 table/entity(cause i'm using ado.net entity data model to generate the database automatically) the problem is when my delete function is executed only ROW from 1 table is deleted..

PS: i've also already create the relationship between 3 table

here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        // i've edited this code, i think the problem lies in this code bellow
        // start edited code
        ms_student ms_student = db.ms_student
             .Include(i => i.ms_person) 
             .Include(i => i.ms_person.ms_user)
             .Where(i => i.user_id_student == id)
             .Single(); 
        // end edited code

        db.ms_student.Remove(ms_student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

this is my ms_user model:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ms_user
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string salt { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> administrative_type_id { get; set; }
        public string email_login { get; set; }

        public virtual ms_person ms_person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is ms_person model:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ms_person
    {  
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> family_id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string phone_address { get; set; }
        public string mobile_phone_number { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_of_bith { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_start { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_end { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string identification_ID { get; set; }
        public string passport { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> user_type_id { get; set; }
        public string file_image { get; set; }

        public virtual ms_student ms_student { get; set; }
        public virtual ms_user ms_user { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Lastly my ms_person model:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ms_student
    {
        public int user_id_student { get; set; }
        public int student_code { get; set; }
        public int course_id { get; set; }
        public string degree { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> current_semester { get; set; }
        public string cuti_session { get; set; }

        public virtual ms_person ms_person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

just you know that the model code is auto generated, i'm using ado.net entity model and the only table/entity that deleted are only the ms_student table(sorry, i'm kinda confused with naming: model or entity or table)

the ID on ms_person are auto increment PK
the ID on ms_user actually the FK also the PK of ms_person
and (foolishly of me for the different naming) user_id_student actually the FK also the PK of ms_person

thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think i just found some solution,
i change my delete controller with this:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        // i change this piece of code, not really sure what it means though
        // very appreciate if somebody can describe it in more humanly or sql language
        ms_person ms_person = db.ms_person
             .Include(i => i.ms_student)
             .Include(i => i.ms_user)
             .Where(i => i.ID == id)
             .Single();

        db.ms_person.Remove(ms_person);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

with this all the record from 3 table is deleted, but i'm not sure this is the best solution, because as you can see i just modified the Include() statement, and i'm not really sure this method can be used on other controller as well...

thank you very much, fell free if somebody can put a better solution for my problem.. :D

Comment: vote up :) but you can also use Single without Where, like this: .Include(i => i.ms_user).Single(i => i.ID == id);

Answer (score 1):

You want to also remove the ms_person and ms_user?

Do this.

```
db.ms_student.Remove(ms_student);
if (ms_student.ms_person != null)
{
   db.ms_person.Remove(ms_student.ms_person);
   if (ms_student.ms_person.ms_user != null)
   {
      db.ms_user.Remove(ms_student.ms_person.ms_user);
   }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Yuliam, unfortunately record on ms_person is not deleted, but the record on ms_student and ms_user is deleted..

i think it because the entity dependency, because ms_user and ms_student actually don't have any PK IF ms_person don't exist, so i'm guessing  that if you want to completely delete all the record  from 3 table, u must make delete the ms_person first... 

Note that i'm not talking about on delete cascade or on update cascade.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteFacilitator( Int64 FacID)
{
  if(FacID == null)
  {
      return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  var Resul= db.NFE_Facilitator.Find(ID);
  if(Resul==null)
  {
      return HttpNotFound();
  }
      return View(Resul);
}
[HttpPost,ActionName("DeleteFacilitator")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed( Int64 ID)
{
   var Resul= db.NFE_Facilitator.Find(ID);
   db.NFE_Facilitator.Remove(Resul);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("SearchFacilitator");
}
```